# How do I change modalTransitionStyle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am currently using this code to bring up an info window

`-(IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {
 InfoView *info = [[InfoView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:info animated:YES];
    [info release];
}`

It currently uses the default transition style, UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical, and I would like to make it use a different transition style, UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal for example, how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from apple documentation
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/Classes_MainViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Classes_MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

```
MusicTableViewController *controller = [[MusicTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MusicTableView" bundle: nil];
controller.delegate = self;

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted note that the 
controller.delegate = self;
line tripped up my program and isn't actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)next {
page2 *page2_xib = [[page2 alloc] init];
page2_xib.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
//page2_xib.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
//page2_xib.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
//page2_xib.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:page2_xib animated:YES];
}
```